# Java - Formatting the date printing

Tags: java, date

I need help to format the date in the code that is below. Should be the date shown on the form: `05. May 2014`. Please give me suggestions how to do it.

```
package person;
public class Person {

public static void main(String[] split) {

    String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
    String[] newText = text.split("[./ ]");
    for(int i=0; i<newText.length; i+=4)
    {
         String name = newText[i].split(" ")[0];
         String lastName = newText[i+1].split(" ")[0];
         String dateOfBirth = newText[i+2].split(" ")[0];
         String placeOfBirth = newText[i+3].split(" ")[0];

         System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", last name: " + lastName + ", date of birth: " + dateOfBirth + ", place of birth: " + placeOfBirth);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Format {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd ',' MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
        String[] newText = text.split("[./ ]");
        for(int i=0; i<newText.length; i+=4)
        {
            String name = newText[i].split(" ")[0];
            String lastName = newText[i+1].split(" ")[0];
            String dateOfBirth = newText[i+2].split(" ")[0];
            String placeOfBirth = newText[i+3].split(" ")[0];


            System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", last name: " + lastName + ", date of birth: " + formatter.format(parser.parse(dateOfBirth)) + ", place of birth: " + placeOfBirth);
        }}


}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works i always thought `m` is for minutes

Comment: @SparkOn tx was coding to fast. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
String dateOfBirth = newText[i+2].split(" ")[0];
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateOfBirth);
SimpleDateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(dF.format(date));
```

Dont forget to handle the exception

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion : use the utility class in the SDK :

- Java 8 : [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- before java 8 : [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and especially [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

Keep in mind that [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is **NOT THREAD SAFE**.

"Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally."

```
    SimpleDateFormat FromDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mmDDyyyy");
    Date date = FromDate.parse("05051988");
    SimpleDateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMM yyyy");
    String result = toFormat.format(date);
```